# how to display count in label text?

Tags: c#, mysql

i am having a hard time to display my count code to my label text. here is my code and please tell me how to solve this problem.

```
ordering_and_billing.dBase dBase = new ordering_and_billing.dBase();
var mydbconnection = new dBase.dbconnection();

string sql = "SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE eventdate='" + lbldte.Text + "'";

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, mydbconnection.Connection);
mydbconnection.Connection.Open();
MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (rdr.HasRows)
{
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        Int32 count = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        string disp = count.ToString();
        lblcount.Text = disp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just use `count` function:

```
string sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `order` WHERE eventdate='" + lbldte.Text + "'";
```

also don't use `ExecuteReader`, use `ExecuteScalar` function if you want a single value like a count value:

```
lblcount.Text =cmd.ExecuteScalar().toString();
```

Comment: This is correct right here, with one caveat.  DO NOT build query strings from user input like this.  Read up a little on what "Sql Injection" is.  The best practice it to use a variable for the input and pass the variable as a parameter to your query.

Comment: yeah but i used this code too. it also work for me thanks about that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `SELECT COUNT(*)` if all you want is the record count.

```
string sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `order` WHERE eventdate='" + lbldte.Text + "'";
```

However, keep in mind that `rdr.Read()` reads a new row from the sql query. *Every* time you get a new row, you're trying to rerun the sql command (which I'm guessing crashes) and then assign the `count` label. So you're trying to assign the `count` label *count* times. Use this construct instead:

```
int count = 0;
while (rdr.Read())
{
    count++;
}
lblcount.Text = count.ToString(); //only assigns to the Text property once
```

Comment: thanks about this this makes my code shorter. haha. how i didnt know that? btw thanks. i put this code in timer i want it every 5sec the codes will refreshed. thanks

Comment: I didn't understand the `I want it every 5 seconds the codes will refreshed` part, but you're welcome :).

Answer (score -1):

never mind guys i got my answer now.

```
ordering_and_billing.dBase dBase = new ordering_and_billing.dBase();
var mydbconnection = new dBase.dbconnection();

string sql = "SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE eventdate='" + lbldte.Text + "'";

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, mydbconnection.Connection);
mydbconnection.Connection.Open();
MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
int count = 0;
while (rdr.Read())
{
    count ++;
}
lblcount.Text = count.ToString();
```

Comment: See my answer. If all you want is count, your sql query should change. And you shouldn't be assigning to `lblcount.Text` *every* time you read a new row.